# cryptage et decryptage rsa sur une image utilisant java netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm working on an application that can encrypt and decrypt an image  (specific selection ) using RSA algorithm, all works well but some pixels are behaving strangely and I can't understand why! I use the same parameters to encrypt/decrypt and save the image and yet, when I create the new image, and try to read the pixels in crypted zone, I don't get the pixel that my program showed me before.

```
File img = new File (Path); 
bf1  = ImageIO.read(img);  
marchdanslImage(bf1,captureRect); // only selected rectangle (captureRect) from image will be treated
```

///////the function i called before

```
private void marchdanslImage(BufferedImage image , Rectangle REC) throws IOException {

    bf2 = new BufferedImage(REC.width, REC.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); //this image gonna contain the pixels after encryption  

    for (int i = y; i < h; i++) {
    for (int j = x; j < w; j++) {
      int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);//orginal values
      printPixelARGB(pixel,j,i); //here i call the code to crypt or decrypt
      bf2.setRGB(j-x,i-y, rgb); //new values
      } }
}
```

the code of the function printPixelARGB:

```
public void printPixelARGB(int pixel,int i , int j) {

 r[i][j] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff; // original values
rr[i][j] = RSA_crypt_decrypt(r[i][j], appel);//values after treatment 
 g[i][j] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
gg[i][j] = RSA_crypt_decrypt(g[i][j], appel);
 b[i][j] = (pixel) & 0xff;
bb[i][j] = RSA_crypt_decrypt(b[i][j], appel);
     rgb = rr[i][j];// new values on rgb to be set in bf2
     rgb = (rgb << 8) + gg[i][j];
     rgb = (rgb << 8) + bb[i][j];
}
```

and finally to save my work:

```
public void save_image()
 {
     Graphics2D g;

     g = (Graphics2D) bf1.getGraphics();
     g.drawImage(bf2, captureRect.x,  captureRect.y,  captureRect.width, captureRect.height, null);
     g.dispose();
   //i draw the crypted pixels on my original image and create new image
    File outputFile = new File("C:/USERS/HP/DesKtop/output.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bf1, "jpg", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MenuGenerale2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

So far everything is working, but when open the image I created, and try to decrypt, the values I get are not the same, after treatment!

Is it because of the saving part? When I try it on a white image it does not work correctly, but on another image it does not at all! It's been 3 weeks couldn't solve this problem... I really really need help.

Here is the link of my application:
[www.fichier-rar.fr/2016/04/23/cryptagersa11/](http://www.fichier-rar.fr/2016/04/23/cryptagersa11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving the image with JPEG compression. JPEG compression does *not* preserve data exactly: it is a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).

If you used, say, BMP or PNG files, the problem would would not happen.

You might want to investigate *steganography*, although I suspect it is the opposite of what you want to achieve

Comment: hey , emmm , i tried .png , had problem with bmp so .., any way it is working with .png extension , i was so stupid , how did i just forget to try others extensions !!! i almost cried -_- 3 weeks imagine that !!
thnx a lot brother.  love you :D